# My RecyclerView doesn't updates (sometimes)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a tabbed activity. In each fragment is a RecyclerView.
My RecyclerView won't update if scroll to other fragments and back for example. If i just start the app it works. To update my RecyclerView i change for example the name in a driffrent activity and call a method in a diffrent class updating my RecyclerView which only sometimes works.

I also tried to update the whole fragment (in `onResume()`) when you exit the activity to change the data and go back to the fragments.

I found out that the problem only shows up when `onCreateView` of the fragment is called a second time.

Here's my Fragment class:

```java
public static class DayFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DayFragment() {

        }

        public static DayFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            DayFragment fragment = new DayFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            Day day = new Day(getArguments().getInt(SECTION_NUMBER, 0) - 1, rootView, getContext(), getContext().getFilesDir());
            MainActivity.DAYS.add(day);
            day.createList();

            System.out.println("CREATED" + (getArguments().getInt(SECTION_NUMBER, 0) - 1));

            return rootView;
        }

    }
```

Setting up the list:

```java
public void createList() {
        dayList = day.findViewById(R.id.dayList); // day is the rootView of the fragment passed on to this object of a class
        lessonsAdapter = new LessonListAdapter();
        dayList.setAdapter(lessonsAdapter);
        dayList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return false;
            }
        });
        dayList.addItemDecoration(new MarginItemDecoration(context));
    }
```

Updating my RecyclerView (in a normal Java class):

```java
public void update() {
        data.clear();
        //if(lessonsAdapter != null) {
        //    lessonsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //}
        data.addAll(newData);
        lessonsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So please tell me what I need to do so that my RecyclerView will update every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, I found the solution, of course my problem was somwhere else.
Im very sorry for consuming your time and thank you for your effort!

The problem was that I added new Day objects to my list without deleting the old ones when `onCreateView` was called, so the new, updated data simply wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and then update the fragment inside

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    ... 
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        ...
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(position);
        if (fragment != null) {
            // Update fragment here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
}
```

Comment: My SectionsPagerAdapter doesn't have the method getFragment, what do you mean by mAdapterViewPager?

Comment: Updated my answer, this might help

Comment: So i wrote `Fragment fragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
        if (fragment != null) {
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }` in `onPageSelected` and the method gets called but it won't update after i scrolled to right and back to the first fragment. Maybe there's something wrong with my update code? Thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: Are you trying to update the `ViewPager` adapter or the list adapter of fragment? I guess `mSectionPagerAdapter` is `ViewPager` adapter. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on list adapter.

Comment: `mSectionsPagerAdapter` is `SectionsPagerAdapter` for the `ViewPager` and I tried to update the whole fragment, but I only need to Update the RecyclerView in it

Comment: Add list update public method in fragment and call that update mehod inside `onPageSelected`

Comment: So I edited my post, bc I figured out something new, probably thats my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the adapter again every time you change the fragment, you can do that onResume. Try something like this:

```
    private void initAdapter(){
    lessonsAdapter = new LessonListAdapter();
    dayList.setAdapter(lessonsAdapter);
    dayList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }
    });
    dayList.addItemDecoration(new MarginItemDecoration(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() { initAdapter(); }
```

Comment: Still doesn't works. I need to init the Adapter again after i changed the value of my data list (in my update() method) right?

Comment: No, after you change the value of your data you have to call lessonsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you have to pass the data to your lessonsAdapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Use Hussain answer and use this code to get your fragment inside `onPageSelected` method

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adaper.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);
```